# How to calculate sum of rows in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

i have a slight different requirement,request you to please read through before marking as duplicate.
Given the example:

```
<table ng:init="stuff={items:[{description:'gadget', cost:99,date:'jan3'},{description:'thing', cost:101,date:'july6'},{description:'thing', cost:101,date:'jan3'} ]}">
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng:repeat="item in stuff.items|filter">   /*only filtered item grouped by date*/    
        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
        <td ng-bind='item.cost'>{{item.cost}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{total}}</td>   /*cost of items grouped by date jan3*/
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do i calculate total cost of group by items?Is there any data-attribute in angular where I can add the cost for a grouped item,then again re-initialize it for the next grouped items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 1.3 added the ability to [create an alias to your `ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), which is very useful when used in conjunction with a filter.

> `variable in expression as alias_expression` – You can also provide an optional alias expression which will then store the intermediate results of the repeater after the filters have been applied. Typically this is used to render a special message when a filter is active on the repeater, but the filtered result set is empty.
>
> For example: `item in items | filter:x as results` will store the fragment of the repeated items as `results`, but only after the items have been processed through the filter.

So, you can use this `as alias_expression` to perform a calculation on the filtered subset of your list. i.e.:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in stuff.items|filter as filteredStuff">
  {{filteredStuff.length}}
  {{calculateTotal(filteredStuff)}}
</tr>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.calculateTotal = function(filteredArray){
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(filteredArray, function(item){
        total += item.cost;
    });
    return total;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own custom filter, that will accept the array will return you the total cost of your all items.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng:repeat="item in filteredData = (stuff.items|filter)">
    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
    <td ng-bind='item.cost'>{{item.cost}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{filteredData| total}}</td>   /*cost of items grouped by date jan3*/
</tr>
```

**Code**

```
app.filter('total', function(){
  return function(array){
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(array, function(value, index){
       if(!isNaN(value.cost))
        total = total + parseFloat(value.cost);
    })
    return total;
  }
})
```

Comment: but I need only those items which where filtered by a date in ng-repeat.

Comment: @curiousUser did you check mine answer?